# Como saber si tengo configurado un proyecto de git (en mi pc) a mi repositorio en la nube?

Tags: github

La cosa es asi: tengo el fork de un bootcamp. Trabaje en una pc y despues en la nueva, pero no recuerdo haber configurado mi perfil de github en la nueva. Quise hacer el push y no pude. Hay alguna fomra de chequearlo?

Comment: ejecutando en la consola el comando `git config --list` ,puedes listar todos los parametros de configuracion de tu repositorio local, alli podras ver que `username`, `email` y demas parametros fueron configurados.

Comment: Mira también `git remote -v` para ver la URL del repositorio remoto a ver si es la que esperas que sea.

Answer (score 0):

cuando clonas un repositorio se te crea una carpeta oculta por defecto
`.git`. Puedes activar la vista de elementos ocultos en Windows 11 desde [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra opción es poner dentro de la carpeta del fork el comando `git status`.